# UI Events Not Working After Switching to Main View from WebView

Tags: android, uitableview, webview, uibutton, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a working Android app that switches its content view to a WebView and returns to the main view when the user closes the web view. After switching back, button events are not working and a ListView isn’t updating even though I call notifyDataSetChanged().  I switch back to the main view inside a Bluetooth call back and do so by running setContentView on the UI thread.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);   <<< EVERYTHING WORKS

setContentView(webView);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);   <<< BUTTONS DON’T WORK LIST VIEW DOESN’T UPDATE


BluetoothGattCallback btGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback()
{
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState)
    {
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "onConnectionStateChange; status: " + status + "; newState: " + newState);

        if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED)
        {
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "BT connected");

            gatt.discoverServices();
        }
        else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED)
        {
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "BT disconnected");

            // Go back to user input and scanner select
            runOnUiThread(new Thread(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    // Clear the scanner list
                    btDeviceList.clear();
                    btDeviceNameList.clear();
                    btDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                     // Start looking for a scanner
                    startBTScan();

                    // Go back to the user input view
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                }
            }));
        }
        else
        {
            Log.e(LOGTAG, "Unhandled BT state change");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you set Click listeners after updating layout?

Comment: I was not resetting them.  The button events work now but the list view still isn't updating.  I reset that to but will into what I am doing more deeply.  Thanks for the quick help.

Comment: Did you set the adapter again to listview ?

Comment: Yup.  That did it.